# Continuity of $\sin(x)/x$ at x=0

Tags: limits, continuity

This was previously asked at [Continuity of $\sin(x)/x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362920/continuity-of-sinx-x), however my particular question was not addressed.

Why are we not able take the Maclaurin expansion of $\sin(x)$ and simply divide by x, to yield 1 - $\frac{x^2}{3!}$ + $\frac{x^4}{5!}$ - $\frac{x^6}{7!}$... which would give us a function that is defined at x=0 to be 1 - $\frac{0}{3!}$ + $\frac{0}{5!}$ - $\frac{0}{7!}$ = 1

Are we not able to due this due to it being incorrect to algebraically manipulate infinite series, or is there some other reason?

Comment: For pity's sake, when you write a formula, put the **whole formula** into MathJax, not just the parts that seem to "need" it!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $\sin(x)/x$ is not defined at $x=0$ even if your function from the Maclaurin expansion is

Comment: Extending the comment of @J.W.Tanner, the flaw in your analysis is that you are not allowed to divide by $~0.~$  So, the step that you take when you divide by $~x,~$ is invalid when applied to the specific value of $~x = 0.$

Answer (score 3):

Short answer. In order to derive the Maclaurin expansion of $\sin x$ you need to know the derivative of $\sin x$ at $0$, which depends on knowing  the limit at $0$ of $(\sin x)/x$ so using the expansion to find that limit is circular reasoning.

Comment: Maybe I defined a series and named it sinx. And then I asked such a question?

Comment: In some book the $\sin$ function of **defined** as it's Maclaurin series. If that's the case you can simply divide the series by $x$.

Comment: @jjagmath See my comment following the original posting.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the reason $\sin(x)/x$ is not defined at $0$ is the same as the reason that $x/x$ is not defined at $0$. It's because the function is defined by an operation that cannot be performed at $x=0$.

The Maclaurin series
$1 - \dfrac{x^2}{3!} + \dfrac{x^4}{5!} - \dfrac{x^6}{7!} \pm \cdots$
works fine as the definition of a function,
but in order to get it from $\sin(x)/x$, you divided the Maclaurin series for $\sin(x)$ by $x$, which is not a defined operation when $x$ is zero.
Therefore the derivation of your function as a series is valid only for non-zero $x$,
and defines the function only for non-zero $x$.

Of course you can easily **extend** the function $\sin(x)/x$ to a continuous function $f$ over all real numbers by "filling in" the function value $f(0) = 1$.
That is what you do when you derive the Maclaurin series of $\sin(x)/x$ for
$x \neq 0$ and then declare it to be a function defined for all real numbers.
This ability to "fill in" an undefined function value was discussed at length in the answers to the linked question.